# Is Postgres cache (shared_buffers) data sorted according to indexes?

Tags: postgresql, caching, indexing

I'm not well versed in Postgres, so bear with me.

Since indexing a table doesn't physically order it on disk according to the index, my question is - is shared_buffers contents ordered according to it?

Comment: I wouldn't expect that. The buffer cache simply caches blocks from the harddisk - it has no notion to which index or table it belongs as far as I know. They might end up next to each other, but that won't last either if blocks are aged out of the cache

Comment: that means only particular index (the one selected by query optimizer) knows the order of the rows (it's in-memory repesentation, but not necessary on-disk one)?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks, I think for a bird-eye view that's good enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When PostgreSQL needs to read an 8K block, it finds the first available clean buffer with usage count 0 and loads the block into it. So (index or table) blocks are in shared buffers in a random fashion.

That shouldn't matter, since memory is random access these days.

According to your comment you actually want to know what is affected by the command `CLUSTER`:

`CLUSTER` rewrites a table so that the rows are physically ordered *on disk* in the logical order of an index. Within one block, that ordering will be preserved when data are in shared buffers (since the block is copied to memory as it is). But different table blocks will not be put into shared buffers close to each other or in any particular order.

The idea is to make sure that an index scan that accesses more than one row only has to read as few table blocks from disk as possible, and those in sequential order. In memory, it does not matter if blocks are read sequentially or not.

Comment: I was wondering in which of those places (table disk files, shared_buffers, index files) data is ordered according to clustered key

Comment: I extended the answer to cover `CLUSTER`.